# Norm of ideal and galois conjugate, why $N((α))=N(( \sigma α))$ holds?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be quadratic number field. Let $Gal(K/ \Bbb{Q})=${$id, \sigma$}.
Let $R_K$ be ring of integers of $K$ and $I$ be ideal of $R_K$.
Then normal of $I$ is defined as$N(I)=$ #$R_K/I$.

Suppose $I$ is principal, $I=(α)$, $α\in  R_K$. Then, why $N((α))=N(( \sigma α))$ holds ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Even if $I$ is not principal, $\sigma$ induces a bijection $R_K/I\to R_K/\sigma(I).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to see this is that $N((\alpha)) = (\mathrm{Nm}(\alpha))$, and $\mathrm{Nm}(\alpha) = \prod_{\tau \in \mathrm{Gal(K/\mathbf{Q})}}\tau\alpha$ is invariant under conjugation by an element $\sigma$ in the Galois group.

See the beginning of Chapter 4 in Milne's notes for more information about norms! https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANTc.pdf